# High availability on Azure Cloud Services using Availability Zones

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-availability-zones

Does Azure Cloud Services support Availability Zones?

1. I can see that the default number of fault domains in cloud services is 5.
2. This number doesn't depend on a region.
3. Number of availability zones is different per region and doesn't exceed 3.

This makes me think that fault domains in cloud services are something different than availability zones.

So, is it possible to leverage the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Azure Cloud Services support Availability Zones?

The short answer is no. For more information, you could look at [Azure services and regions that support Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region#services-support-by-region).